# How much funds do I need in my bank account to apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, proof-of-funds

I am an owner of a little business in India and will support the visa application with firm's legit papers along comes the bank statement of my business accounting too. However do I also have to show the bank statement of my  saving's account?

If yes than how much amount is sufficient ?

Comment: Does the application require an invitation letter?

Comment: not mandatory but they have an option, if you know some body their

Comment: And what's your question exactly? The title concerns an invitation letter, but the only questions in the body concern bank statements.

Comment: I mostly use my business Acc to support myself and i keep a little in my savings Acc. However, if I transfer funds from my business account to the savings Acc at the time of applying for visa, would it be taken as "funds parking"???

Comment: Probably, but you should edit your question to make that clear and change the title to remove reference to the invitation letter to keep the question focused. You could ask that as a separate question. Is your business a separate legal entity? If so are you its sole owner? If not are you the owner of the business account?

Comment: Yes the business is a separate legal entity and i am not a sole owner of the company i have 25% stakes of the company as its partnership firm

Comment: no i am not the sole owner of the business account too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: I am voting to leave open because this is a Schengen question and while the UK question is related it is never the same question and the Schengen case is not addressed there.

Comment: @Willeke there's a difference between Schengen and UK. Voting to keep open.

Comment: Oops, missed that, will withdraw the vote.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which country's consulate or embassy you are applying to;
most embassies expect 50 to 60 Euros for each day of your stay in the Schengen area.

Yes, you always need to show all relevant documents with your application, including bank statements.

I got Schengen visas 15 times from different states and my stay was never 
more than 15 days. Besides travelling costs, I always showed at least 4 to 5 thousand Euros in my account.

Comment: The issue actually is not the money, its all about funds parking if i put money in my savings account from my business account, the consulate might think that i av just park funds to make my application look better

Comment: usually consulates ask bank statements for last 6 months to 1 year just to make sure that statements are legitimate.you can transfer your funds from your business account to savings account as long as you are maintaining your savings account in a good shape for at least 6 months.Otherwise they might consider it artificial boost at the last moment before applying for a visa

Comment: That the whole issue that i have not maintained it well but i have money and i am applying it in 10 days and stressed as well about this

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the purpose and nature of your trip.  There is no set amount for the Schengen zone, each country is free to determine their own requirements; sometimes they even list this on their foreign mission / embassy websites.

For example, [the Netherlands](https://www.government.nl/topics/visa-for-the-netherlands-and-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom/question-and-answer/which-visa-do-i-need-to-travel-to-the-netherlands):

"You also should be able to prove you have sufficient funds for your stay in the Schengen area. In the Netherlands this is a minimum of € 34 per person per day. In some cases, such checks may result in a refusal for the visa holder to enter the Schengen country or the Schengen area."

For Italy, there is this [handy PDF (in Italian)](http://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/Moduli/it/Direttiva_MinInterno_1-3-2000.pdf) which has on its last page a table that lists the fees for the lenght of stay, and number of travelers.

Comment: This is now 55 EUR per person per day in the Netherlands.